# disable and change button icon after added/clicked c# asp .net mvc5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to change button icon and disable the button after I clicked/added the object.
I thought to use javascript to accomplish this handling.

something like this:

**--javascript--**

```
  $('#catBut').click(function(){
  $(this).find('span')
       .toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-plus')
       .toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok'); 
  })
```

;

**--view--**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "VerlangLijst", new { naam = materiaal.Naam }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    <button id="catBut" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </button>
}
```

But somehow it doesn't  work. I have added the new .js file to the bundleConfig.

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-plus').toggleClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
```

to

```
$(this).find('span').addClass('glyphicon-ok').removeClass('glyphicon-plus');
```

To disable the button:

```
$('#catBut').prop("disabled",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the button, try something like :

```
$('#catBut').click(function(){
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus').toggleClass('glyphicon-ok'); 
    $('#catBut').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

This will remove the "plus" icon from the button, add the "ok" icon and set disabled=true on button "catBut", hence disabling it.

You may also try (if the above solution doesn't work) :

```
$(document).on("click", "#catBut", function(){
    $('#catBut').find('span').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').addClass('glyphicon-ok'); 
    $('#catBut').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on("click", "#catBut", function(){
    $('#catBut').find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus').toggleClass('glyphicon-ok'); 
    $('#catBut').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: hmm I tried all these options. No reaction at all. Is it possible I forgot kind of import statement for the .js file?

Comment: Make sure you are including jquery in your code correctly before using any of these scripts..